# Custom JS in Magento2 product page

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, plugin, requirejs

(This is the plugin I am trying to use)
http://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty

I have

```
app/design/frontend/myvendor/mytheme/requirejs-config.js
```

and it looks like:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        'eventmove':        'Magento_Theme/js/jquery.event.move',
        'twentytwenty':     'Magento_Theme/js/jquery.twentytwenty'
    },
    shim: {
        'twentytwenty': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }

   }

};
```

cleared pub folder, set development mode, re-compile, deploy static files...

viewing source on front end reveals the js files are not loaded.

also, this is the code on the detail page that it needs, I dont knwo if it's formatted right or not since requirejs isnt working.

```
<script>
    require([
    'jquery',
    'eventmove',
    'twentytwenty'
    ], function () {
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery(window).load(function() {
          jQuery(".twentytwenty-container").twentytwenty();
      });
    });
</script>
```

***EDIT***
[image: description of errors]

Comment: Is there any browser console error?

Answer (score 2):

Magento2 uses RequireJS to load javascript modules, you should use this to integrate the module with the standard jQuery library. You should place a `requirejs-config.js` file in your custom theme. This file is used by Magento for locating JS modules, like for example twentytwenty.

Example `requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        'twentytwenty':        'Magento_Theme/js/twentytwenty' 
    },
    shim: {
        'twentytwenty': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }

   }
};
```

`paths` is used by Magento2 to locate the main JS module. `Shim` makes sure that it is loaded after jQuery

File location: `app/design/frontend/Your/CustomTheme/Magento_Theme/web/js/twentytwenty.js`

In your template PHTML:

```
<script>
    require([
    'jquery',
    'twentytwenty'
    ], function () {
      jQuery(window).load(function() {
         jQuery("#container1").twentytwenty();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Do not add JS files directly to the `<head>` tag. You can find more documentation about RequireJS here: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_and_requirejs/

Comment: Thanks so Much @N-Bursma I edited the original question to reflect the new changes, I tried that, and it requirejs isn't loading the .js at all

Comment: What kind of error does the console give you? I'm not sure that the location `'js/jquery.event.move'` is correctly. Try to stick with `Magento_Theme/js/twentytwenty` for now, I can confirm that this locations is working.

Comment: I've also updated the PHTML snippet, you should try that code. Make sure that you delete the requirejs file in the /pub folder. Also try to open the page with cache disabled or in incognito mode.

Comment: thanks so much, so changing it to Magento_Theme/js/**** it still doesn't work... the console shows a: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/CVP/CVPStyle1-2/en_US/twentytwenty.js'

Comment: I've added the exact file location to the answer. Can you compare this to the location of your twentytwenty.js file? Make sure that you aren't missing the `web` folder in `Magento_Theme`, which is standard for js/css/images.

Comment: I added screenshot, showing the files, location, and browser console error.

Comment: I can't find errors in your code. Somehow your requirejs config isn't loaded by Magento2, so it doesn't know the right path. You could check out the file `pub/static/_requirejs/frontend/your/theme/requirejs-config.js` and check if your config is present. If not, try to delete this file and see if the newly generated requirejs-config.js has the right config. If your config is present here, i'm guessing that it has something to do with browser cache.

Comment: thanks, I have checked and that file does not exist in the pub folder, the only thing in pub folder under the theme, is en_US, and even in there, no requirejs-config.js exists.

Comment: So the folder `~/magento_root/pub/static/__requirejs/frontend/your/theme` doesn't exist? Did you by any chance delete the .htaccess file in the pub folder? If this file doesn't exist then you've made a mistake somewere else. Your JS looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

@Tjitse:

Have you tried to wrap the 3rd party JS library (code in the jquery.twentytwenty.js) in "define", as follows:

```
define(["jquery"], function($){
    (function($){
        $.fn.twentytwenty = function(options) ...
        // ... the rest of library code ...
        // ...
    })(jQuery);
});
```

Doing this should make sure your code runs after the dependencies are loaded.

BTW, your requirejs-config.js looks just fine, but I guess the jquery.event.move.js also requires jquery?

Comment: I'm sure jquery.event.move.js does also require jquery. so are you saying to modify the  jquery.twentytwenty.js file to have the 'define' as you posted?

Comment: Yes, basically. Define ensures requirements are loaded before

Comment: You can also use AMD features (many recent jquery libs and jquery itself do that)